# How to install eclipse php in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, apache2, php, eclipse, web-development

I have php,mySql and apache2 installed but I needed a IDE for development.So How can I download Eclipse Php with out any errors please help me.
And Help me in supporting installed apace2,mySql and php in to it!!

Comment: There are other questions to search for about installing apache, mysql and php, you can also start by reading the documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Answer (score 4):

You can not install Eclipse over the repositories and Software Center or apt-get.

You will have to visit https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/lunasr2 and download the right version (Linux 32/64Bit).

Then extract the tar.gz-archive (about 100-150MB) to your `/opt` directory. You need root privileges to access that folder, so run your filemanager as root (e.g. `gksu nautilus`) or work with `sudo` and terminal commands (`cd /opt/ && sudo tar -zxvf /full/path/to/eclipse-*.tar.gz`)

Next step is to create a launcher for eclipse:
Open an root-editor window on the new file with `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse_php.desktop` and paste the following lines into it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse PHP
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/<your_eclipse_path>/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/<your_eclipse_path>/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse PHP
StartupWMClass=Eclipse_PHP
```

Save and close it. Now Eclipse should appear in your dash application lens. If not, you might have to run `sudo desktop-file-install /usr/share/applications/eclipse_php.desktop`.

That's it. You can now start Eclipse and do the necessary configurations.

You might want to have a look at this guide too:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-latest-eclipse-ubuntu-14-04/
Note that it was written for the outdated "Kepler" version (current = March 2015 is Luna) and the standard Java IDE components, not PHP.

Comment: didn't work, how to I run the eclipse after going through the steps?

Comment: @EliaWeiss The described procedure is outdated. Current Eclipse versions come with an installer that will place the IDE in your home directory. Just download it from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and run it.